# Set the xlink:href attribute of an svg <image> element with CSS

Tags: css, image, svg, href, xlink

I need to set the 'xlink:href' attribute on an svg `<image>` element, described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag).

Can I do this with CSS?

Comment: No, it's not possible to set attributes using CSS.

Comment: This is the list of properties you can style with CSS in svg. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `xlink:href` isn't a CSS property. See the [list of css properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/propidx.html) required in SVG 1.1.